# How to use ESLint and Prettier within a Razzle, React and TypeScript project inside VS Code in 2021?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I want to use both ESLint and Prettier within a project that uses both React and TypeScript inside VS Code (through Razzle, if it is relevant). I do not have preferences yet regarding the code style and formatting but I wish some common sense. The following are my configuration files. I insist upon the idea that I do not have clear tastes regarding the code style and formatting and I wish some good defaults.

I have installed both the ESLint and Prettier VS Code extensions.

In the project I have the following packages installed:

```json
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.0",
"eslint": "^7.29.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
"eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.4.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
"eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
"eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.5.4",
"razzle-plugin-eslint": "^4.0.4",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
"prettier": "^1.19.1",
```

And I have the following issues:

1. Prettier tries to put double quotes around strings and ESLint tries to put single quotes around strings. I do a change and the opposite is shown as recommended with red squiggles under strings.

I wish to have common style and linting in `.tsx` files, in general. The others are not so important. I have watched [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfyI9yl3qfE) about this but it is from 2018 and it seems to not work in present for me.

## `.eslintrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    "prettier",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
    "airbnb"
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: "./tsconfig.json",
    tsconfigRootDir: "./",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    "prettier",
    'react',
    '@typescript-eslint',
    "import",
  ],
  rules: {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
    'import/extensions': ['off'],
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, { extensions: ['.tsx', '.jsx'] }],
    'import/prefer-default-export': [0],
    'import/order': [0],
  },
  settings: {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {},
    },
  },
};
```

## `.prettierrc.json`

```json
{}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm i -D eslint-config-prettier

...

// .eslintrc.json

"extends": [
  ...
  "prettier"
],
```

That package is meant to disable the eslint rules interfering with prettier.  After that you actually need to configure your `.prettierrc.json`, currently it's empty.

```
// .prettierrc.json

{
  "singleQuote": false,
}
```

Comment: I get errors like this: `Strings must use singlequote. eslint (quotes)`.

Comment: Move ````"prettier"```` to the last item in your array.  Completely uninstall ````eslint-plugin-prettier```` and just use ````prettier --write````, that plugin is crap.